# Let $g$ be continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$. If $g(0)= g(1) = 0$, prove that $g'(x) = g(x)$ has a solution

Tags: real-analysis

I try to use Darboux's Thm and IVT but end up stuck. Is using mean-value theorem many time can get the result?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2021877/42969

Comment: @MartinR This is very slick, and of course answers the question. But it'd be wonderful to get an answer which explains *why* a student (or anyone) should think of the neat proxy function.

Comment: thanks, got it now :)

Comment: @ClementC. The hypotheses look like those of Rolle's theorem.  So we look for a function $f$ that will be $0$ when $g(x) = 0$ and whose derivative will be $0$ when $g'(x) = g(x)$.  The first condition will be true if $f(x) = h(x) g(x)$ for some $h$.  The second will be true if $h'(x) = -h(x)$. And what function satisfies $h'(x) = -h(x)$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I understand that. My point was that it'd be great to add that insight to the answer (instead of only having the rabbit out of the hat trick).

Comment: @ClementC.: I have added something to the older answer (which is essentially what Robert said).

Comment: Thank you for this!